# PHP Input type "datetime-local": value not showing when in edit mode

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, stored-procedures

```
            Pick up Date
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control"          name="DatePickUp" id="DatePickUp" value="{{$pb->DatePU}}">
                  </div>
```

I'm trying to display the date from my database when I'm editing the value, but every time I click on edit, it shows an empty form and I have to put the date again.

I tried changing input type to "date" and it's working fine, but when I tried changing it into "datetime-local" , it's not displaying the value in edit mode.

Comment: How "DatePU" is stored? Means which is type of "DatePU".

Comment: Do you mean the data type ? It is datetime